# Does the infinite product $\prod_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty {\frac{2^n}{3^n}}$ diverge to zero or some other finite value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

Does the  infinite product diverge to zero or some other value?

$$\prod_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty {\frac{2^n}{3^n}}$$

Comment: It's an infinite product, not a series.

Comment: The correct terminology is : "it diverges to 0", consider taking the logarithm of this product and looking at the sum.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my amateurish mistakes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider $$P_m=\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{2^n}{3^n}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{m(m+1)/2}$$

Then, $$P_{\infty}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n}=\lim_{m\to\infty}P_m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{m(m+1)/2}=0$$

Comment: Why is it so big?

Comment: @Potato: with \frac it's too small and with \dfrac it's too big.

Comment: I personally don't think it's too small with \frac. But to each their own, I suppose.

Comment: You can [scale rendered math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9383/5531) for yourself if you find it too small.  There's no need to use commands like `\large`, really.

Comment: Better like this, no?

Comment: As Little wrote in his Miscellany (from memory), "In a paper with Hardy, the last phrase was "... where $\sigma$ is to be made as small as possible." The published paper did not include this phrase. However, a close examination shows that a microscopically small $\sigma$ was where the phrase should have been. The printers must have scoured all of London to find it."

Comment: I guess, @martycohen, that’s Littlewood.